Material Card View position reset after child view set visible/gone
Code reproduction
This is material catlog App.
xml file:cat_card_draggable_fragment.xml
code file:io.material.catalog.card.DraggableCardFragment.java
In xml File add id to TextView:
<TextView
  android:id="@+id/text_view"
  ...

In code file add onClickListener:
card = view.findViewById(R.id.draggable_card);
card.setAccessibilityDelegate(cardDelegate);
container.addDraggableChild(card);
card.setOnClickListener(v -> { // here add
  View viewById = v.findViewById(R.id.text_view);
  if (viewById.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE) {
    viewById.setVisibility(View.GONE);
  } else {
    viewById.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
  }
});


Run app -> Cards -> Draggable Card.
Click card View ,textView toggle visible/gone. (edit success).
drag card view and then clcik card view ,card view reset positoon to canter.
Why does the location change and How to fix it.

I am unable to find any related questions online.
Try set postion of view when onViewReleased in ViewDragListener:
override fun onViewReleased(
    view: View,
    v: Float,
    v1: Float
) {
    val x = if (view.x > width - (view.x + view.width)) {
        width - view.width
    } else {
        0
    }
    if (viewDragHelper.smoothSlideViewTo(view, x, view.top)) {
        view.post {
            while (viewDragHelper.continueSettling(false));
            view.x = x.toFloat()
            view.y = view.y
        }
    }
    if (viewDragListener != null) {
        viewDragListener!!.onViewReleased(view, v, v1)
    }
      invalidate()
}

but not working.
My goal is to be able to move around the entire fragment, click to expand or hide information

My grammar may have many errors, please forgive me

